# В каком формате нужно отправлять данные назад

Tags: php, ajax

Обнаружил на просторах данного форума данный скрипт:

```
      if ($num!=2){
     ?>
        <script>
        function check(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'file.php', //В этом файле делаете запрос в БД и возвращаете результат
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.num!=2){
                        check();
                    }else{
                        alert('OK');
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
        <?php 
    }
```

В каком формате нужно вернуть данные что бы высветился алерт?

Comment: В коде вполне себе написано в каком формате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это json формат.
Получить можно из массива с помощью [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

```php
json_encode( ['num'=>2] );
```

`{ num: 2 }`